# Usage of startActivity from a Navigation package

Tags: java, android, android-intent, package

First at all, I'm a newbie and pure autodidact developer on Android platform. My knowledge of java is still very low but I made progresses since 2 weeks :-)

I've got dozen of Activities with navigation buttons (pref, next, ...). For all those buttons, I've
integrated into the right buttons of the current activity class such a method :

```
private void showPrevActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("ThePrevActivity");
    this.startActivity(intent);
}

private void showNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("TheNextActivity");
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It was OK until the user said me that the linear way to navigate into the application could be easier by adding new buttons. Now, the final application would be like a spider web.

So, I'd like to create a package aka Navigation and add into this package
all the showX methods (or, best way, a generic showActivity method). I created this one

```
package fr.demo.appli.navigation;
import android.content.Intent;
public class Navigation {
    // Add Show Methods to display all the Activities
    public static void showLogin() {
        //...
}
    public static void showOneActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("OneActivity");
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't have access to 'this' into my Navigation class. I guess I'm
very low leveled to see how to do that. Any help / advices would be very useful.

Thank you,

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the solution (I realize that I really need to enhance my Java level...).
I hope it will help other users.

First, I created a package Navigation with all my stuff inside (my purpose is also to
bypass the limit of Eclipse about Activities names autocompletion.

First, I created my package as described :

```
package fr.demo.appli.navigation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Navigation {
    public static class Screens {
        //
        public static String Activity1Activity = "Activity1Activity";
        public static String Activity2Activity = "Activity2Activity";
    }
    public static void showActivity(Activity curActivity, String nextActivityName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(nextActivityName);
        curActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then, inside my code, I just need to call my showActivity method as following :

For exemple #1 : inside a click listener

```
Navigation.showActivity(ActivityName.this, Navigation.Screens.Activity1Activity);
```

For exemple #2 : simplest call

```
Navigation.showActivity(this, Navigation.Screens.Activity1Activity);
```

So, I guess that most advanced users (rest of the world) will probably found some enhancements, adjustments. But, according my case, it works perfectly and it will save me a lot of time.